# Genshi for loop not working...?

Tags: python, genshi

I'm having trouble using a Genshi `py:for` attribute. What have I done wrong? Code written out below; to run, make a virtualenv with Python 2, do `pip install genshi flask`, copy the files as listed in an isolated directory, and run `python hello.py`

### The code

Contents of `hello.py`:

```
import os.path
import traceback

import flask
import genshi.template


app = flask.Flask(__name__)
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
loader = genshi.template.TemplateLoader(template_dir, auto_reload=True)


MESSAGES = [
    "Hello",
    "World",
    "Sup?",
]


@app.route("/", defaults={"name": ""})
@app.route("/<path:name>")
def show(name):
    template_name = name + ".html"
    try:
        template = loader.load(template_name)
        stream = template.generate(
            messages=MESSAGES,
        )
        rendered = stream.render('html', doctype='html')
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        return "Cannot load /{}: {} <pre>\n{}</pre>".format(name, e, tb)

    return rendered


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Contents of `templates/debug.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:py="http://geshi.edgewall.org/"
    >
  <body>
    <p>Messages is a ${str(type(messages))} of length ${len(messages)}</p>

    <p>Messages:</p>
    <pre>
${'\n'.join(m + "!" for m in messages)}
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Contents of `templates/hello.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:py="http://geshi.edgewall.org/"
    >
  <body>
    <h1>Messages</h1>

    <ul>
        <li py:for="msg in messages">
            $msg
        </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

### The problem

When I visit `http://localhost:5000/debug` everything seems to work as expected, but when I run `http://localhost:5000/hello` I get "Cannot render /hello: 'msg' not defined"

Comment: looks like `$msg` should be `${msg}` based on the [docs](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/xml-templates.html#id3)

Comment: The `${msg}` snytax is just an alternative if the expression is complex, similar to what exists in BASH and PHP. Switching to `${msg}` still gives the same error and as far as I can tell is semantically equivalent to `$msg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an 'n' in your namespace definition. It currently reads 
'xmlns:py="http://geshi.edgewall.org/"' but it should read 'xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"'. This causes Genshi to not recognize the 'py:for' attribute and then happily try to evaluate the '$msg' without any 'for msg in messages' to define the variable.